# Rails 4 - Want To Have Rails Use My Local Time Zone for created_at & updated_at

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there actually a way to have Rails add/update rows with created_at and update_at using the current time zone as set on my server?

I have seen many Stack Overflow solutions where people stated how to display it on a Rails view with a selected time zone.

I have also found other Stack Overflow solutions stating that it should take the time zone from my server and update created_at and updated_at.  This is not true at least for the Mac Mini Server I'm running on.  I have it set to my local time zone.  I also have `config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'` set in config/application.rb.

I want to be able to look at the raw database data in pgAdmin3 or some kind of database backup and know when records have been created in my time zone.

Any help would be appreciated.  I will keep looking.

Comment: For fellow rookies, who find this, storing time in the db in your timezone is a bad idea. You should almost always store it as UTC and then convert it to your own, or your users timezone when displayed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to set the db timezone and you are using ActiveRecord, then add the following in your application config:

```
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
```

This will use your sever's timezone on the database.

Comment: It worked.  I did a rake db:seed to test this.  When I looked at my records they had the current central time.  Thanks!

Comment: I am using rails 5.2, and have all these     config.time_zone = "Pacific Time (US & Canada)"
    config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
    config.beginning_of_week = :sunday
    config.active_record.time_zone_aware_types = [:datetime] in my application rb, yet still when rails c my records there are not saved in local time. any idea?

Answer (score 7):

```
# application.rb:
class Application < Rails::Application
  config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
end

Time.zone      # => #<TimeZone:0x514834...>
Time.zone.name # => "Eastern Time (US & Canada)"
Time.zone.now  # => Sun, 18 May 2008 14:30:44 EDT -04:00
```

Please refer following link >>http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html#method-c-5B-5D

Answer (score 2):

You can also run `rake time:zones:all` in order to list all time zones Rails knows. You can then update your setting in application.rb accordingly.